# change the color of the two buttons in Android

Tags: android

Change the color of the two buttons when its correct
I have a game, comparing buttons from the left side and the right side.
when you click on the left side and compare it to right side and its correct  the 2 buttons must be  color green. How can i implement it?

```
public void getClick1(int num)
{
     firstClick = arrNum1[num]; 
}

public void getClick2(int num){
     secondClick = arrNum2[num];
        if (firstClick == secondClick){
            guess.setText(Integer.toString(--score ));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
}
```

Comment: Use booleans and ints for simple logic.. Check with a statement..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the `Button` with this method:

```
btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

... where `btn2` is the instance of `Button`.